# How can I send a request to another server from my controller?

Tags: c#, httpclient, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to send a request from my controller to another server, but it does not return the result ... Nothing at all.

```
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class GetPriceController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<string>> Get()
        {
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(@"client.pfx", "password"));

            var HttpCl = new HttpClient(handler);

            var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://foobar.com:777")
            {
                Content = new StringContent("data")
            };

            var response = await HttpCl.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

After the SendAsync command, nothing happens.

```
   var response = await HttpCl.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
```

Comment: Have you looked at a network capture tool like fiddler to see if your request actually made it out of the application? Is it just taking a long time to process on the requested server's end?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# post to different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679431/c-sharp-post-to-different-server)

Comment: Do *not* create a new `HttpClient` in an action. `HttpClient` connections are somewhat persistent, and you'll easily bump into your server's connection limit. Use `IHttpClientFactory` to manage your clients.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I know about it, I read the documentation. This is a test query, it works fine in the console and returns the result.

Comment: Shouldn’t return something like `return Ok(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());` since the signature of the method expects an `ActionResult<string>` and not just a `string`?

Comment: @Kzrystof Cool thing about `ActionResult<T>` is that a `T` can be implicitly converted to a `ActionResult<T>`, so you can return a string just fine and it will be treated as an `Ok(someValue);`. Of course, this is just shorthand, so your method will also work.